# GWT and Google data APIs in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, google-api

Can I please get a set of instructions for getting Google Data API integration with a GWT application?  I have tried a lot of different methods (including not using GWT), but I can't seem to find a way to get them both to work together.  The most recent fiasco was installing Maven and following the instructions for Google data API access on that, but then I couldn't get the thing to run as a GWT application any more.

I am going to stick with GWT, but can someone please tell me how to get Google Data API into my app on the server-side?  I am using Eclipse.  Specifically, I want do do something like pull real-time stock quotes from the finance service, to feed into the sample stock application ( I followed through the tutorials for that).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Google API Java Client](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-oauth-appengine-sample/instructions.html?r=default) to talk to APIs from your server. There is an [example of using this library on the server to talk to a GWT app](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-oauth-appengine-sample/instructions.html?r=default).

Comment: Thanks, Jason.  I've been beating my head against the wall the whole day today.  I've got a similar setup to the example you provided already.  I copied the api client.jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder, and modified the build path to include the api jars (the main jar and the sources one).

I keep getting the same error:

Comment: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.wakensoft.nograding.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator
 at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378)

Comment: The main error message is actually "Server class 'org.apache.http.client.HttpClient' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath"

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: That probably means that httpClient.jar is on the Tomcat/Jetty classpath but is not included in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your .war file.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working; I'll include the steps that worked for me below for anyone that is having the same problem (I'm using Helios).

- Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
- Add External JARs (go find google-api-client-1.2.2-alpha.jar on your com)
- Expand the new entry, and for Source Attachments, pick google-api-client-1.2.2-alpha-sources.jar
- Flip to "Order and export" and check the box and place it above GWT
- Navigate to "Run/Debug Settings" in the left nav
- Choose the correct entry and then -> Edit
- -> Classpath
- Under "User Entries" you need to Add External JARs for a lot of files - they are all under "Dependencies" in the location that you extracted the api files
- After you've added them all to the bottom, you can come out of Properties
- Go to the location you downloaded the api to, and then copy the api file, the sources file (not sure if this one matters), and all the dependency files and then paste them into the WEB-INF/lib folder in eclipse.

Server-side API code should now work.  There seems to be an RPC failure when I upload to an actual server, but this works on my dev machine using the local jetty.

Hope it helps someone out there; I can't believe it took 2 days to try and fix this.